# is There a way to share vtkActors between two pclViewers?

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, point-cloud-library

I am working on a c++ application with [vtk](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/Main_Page) , pcl and qt.

- **First of all i want to know if it is safe to share the same vtkActors between multible vtkRenderWindows.**

I am using vtk with pcl like this:

- **qt** for user interface:
    **QVTKOpenGLWidget** is a qt widget for displaying the vtk 
    renderWindow "**vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow**"
- **pcl** to view pointcloud on the renderwindow: Iam using 
  pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer class to view pointcloud on the 
  renderWindow.
- **vtk** to add vtk Widgets such as vtkBoxWidget2 to the renderWindow.

  this code demonstrates how i am combining vtk with pcl :

  ```
  QVTKOpenGLWidget *m_qvtkWidget = new QVTKOpenGLWidget;
  auto renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
  auto _renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow>::New();   
  ui->splitterVertical->addWidget(m_qvtkWidget);
  _renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
  pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::Ptr m_pclViewer;
  m_pclViewer.reset(new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer(renderer, _renderWindow, "viewer", false));
  ```

  I'm able to do the following  only if i have pure vtk RenderWindow(not combined with pcl viewer) :
  add my RenderWindow actors to a new renderWindow using vtkActorCollection 
  class like this:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < renderWindowRight->GetRenderers()->GetFirstRenderer()->GetActors()->GetReferenceCount(); i++) {
  auto Actor = renderWindowRight->GetRenderers()->GetFirstRenderer()->GetActors()->GetNextActor();
  Actor->GetProperty()->SetColor(12,15,15);
  renderWindowLeft->GetRenderers()->GetFirstRenderer()->AddActor(Actor);}
  ```

  As I have PclViewer with The renderWindow set within it Previous code does not 
  work.
- **What I tried :**

  1- getting the pclShapeActorMap and use the same vtkProps in the both pclViewers:

  ```
    auto ShapeActorMap = m_pclViewer->getShapeActorMap();
    // m_pclViewer is my main pcl viewer
    // m_pclViewportViewer is viewport  pcl viewer
    for (auto it = ShapeActorMap->begin(); it != ShapeActorMap->end(); ++it) {
    it->second->ShallowCopy(it->second);
    m_pclViewportViewer->getRendererCollection()->GetFirstRenderer()- >SetViewport(viewport);}
  ```

  and also this does not work and I am getting weird output in the pclViewer these two images descripe the output:
- [Main pclViewer before calling previous code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBud0.png)
- [both pclViewers after calling previous code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEcpY.png)

  2- Share the VtkRenderers Between the both PclViewers:

  ```
  auto renderer = m_pclViewer->getRendererCollection()->GetFirstRenderer();
  m_pclViewportViewer->getRenderWindow()->AddRenderer(renderer);
  ```

  [Image of the ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gdd6.png)
  here the pclViewer of the new viewport works fine but the original pclViewer Freezes.
- **So, If this is safe, I am wondering if there is a way to achieve what i am trying to do.**